# CORS issue only when revoking Token by calling (Google Identity Services) GIS's google.accounts.oauth2.revoke

Tags: javascript, browser, oauth-2.0, google-identity, google-identity-toolkit

I am trying to invoke GSI Javascript [`google.accounts.oauth2.revoke`](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.oauth2.revoke) method. Under the hood it sends a request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke. However there is CORS issue:

```js
await new Promise(r => google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token, r));
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke' from origin 'https://localhost:44397' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

These are CORS-related response headers:

- access-control-allow-origin: https://localhost:44397
- access-control-expose-headers: date,vary,vary,vary,content-encoding,server,content-length

All other functions are working well however. Is it a bug on Google's side or my code? If it's Google's where do I report it? If it's my issue, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. I added "localhost" to "Authorised JavaScript origins" for the oauth app

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue also. Even if I added "localhost" with the right port to the "Authorised JavaScript origins" for the oauth of the app, still doesn't work.

Comment: Since there seem to be no official response from Google here, I submitted [an issue to Google here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/821).

Comment: Same issue. But regardless, the user is logged out afterwards so not a huge concern

Comment: When user logs out he assumes that the credentials are revoked, so it is a real problem. Once users logs in again he is surprised that the app still has unexpected permissions.

Answer (score 0):

`revoke()` should now be working as intended, and expected with CORS.

Comment: Can anyone confirm please? Sorry I am not with any project that uses GSI now so I can't confirm

Comment: Still broken for myself

Comment: Can you share details of your setup:  using http/https, localhost/FQDN. It would also be very helpful to include values of the Access-Control-* headers being used.